# Node.js "Cannot read property 'userAgent' of undefined" on require

Tags: node.js, require

Edit4:  I'm happy working in this in Linux now, as I got the rest of the kinks with where to place and how to copy the files out of the way for the project.  Going to go ahead and accept the answer and close this out.

Edit3:  I have a workaround in place for the moment, namely working out of my Debian VM instead of Windows, thanks to Len's comments.  However, I am leaving this unanswered for now to see if someone can solve the Windows problem.

I have slowly been working my way through an install of Node.js on my Windows 7 desktop.  I say slowly because every step of the way has had issues, from PATH variables not updating, to not knowing I needed python, to npm permissions errors. Anyway, I've worked through a ton of them with Google's help, but this has me completely stumped:

```
D:\Website\Webscraper>node webscrape.js

node.js:201
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
              ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'userAgent' of undefined
    at D:\Website\Webscraper\node_modules\jquery\lib\node-jquery.js:87:23
    at D:\Website\Webscraper\node_modules\jquery\lib\node-jquery.js:995:2
    at create (D:\Website\Webscraper\node_modules\jquery\lib\node-jquery.js:9416:2)
    at D:\Website\Webscraper\node_modules\jquery\lib\node-jquery.js:9422:18
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Website\Webscraper\node_modules\jquery\lib\node-jquery.js:9424:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:441:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:459:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:348:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:308:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
```

Here's my entire code:

```
var $ = require('jquery');
```

After endless errors about missing packages, I have the following installed locally via npm:

- jquery@1.7.2
- htmlparser@1.7.6
- jsdom@0.2.14
- cssom@0.2.3
- request@2.9.202
- xmlhttprequest@1.3.0
- location@0.0.1
- navigator@1.0.1

But since the error I am now getting is a pretty generic JS error, and searching for it specifically has netted 0 google hits, I am stumped.  All I want to do is run jquery in node.js.  This was supposed to require ~3 lines of input.  What the heck am I missing?

Edit:  Looking into the navigator.userAgent end of things, it looks like the navigator package I downloaded is meant to fix this, but it's not working.  I also tried editing node-jquery in the jquery module, overriding the global variable "navigator" with one that sets my own userAgent, and a couple other things, but nothing even changes the error, much less fixes the problem.

Edit2:  (fixed for Debian, see comments under Len's answer)

Comment: Well, this is the line you're looking for, hope it'll help: https://github.com/coolaj86/node-jquery/blob/master/lib/node-jquery.js#L87

Comment: Interesting...  That looks like jquery is expecting a browser userAgent, but I'm running it in node.js, so there is none.  Isn't there supposed to be a wrapper that gets around that?  *goes off googling again*

Comment: https://github.com/mikeal/spider this is a web spider running on nodejs and using jQuery to get content on pages. I've used it sucessfully for some minor stuff and build another project on it requiring some tweaking, but it does the basics and should help you either find your way around your error or a base for what seems to be a web crawler project.

Comment: Hmmm, it looks like you aren't using the jquery package, but instead including it manually.  That might be a way to work around the problem, but I would much rather use the standard package.  Thanks for posting your project anyway, though, I'll definitely take a look at it for general ideas once I a base up and running!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works for me!

```
aeka ~/test$ cat webscrape.js 
var $ = require('jquery');
aeka ~/test$ node webscrape.js 
aeka ~/test$ echo $?
0
aeka ~/test$ npm ls
/Users/annelicuss/test
├─┬ jquery@1.7.2 
│ ├── htmlparser@1.7.6 
│ ├─┬ jsdom@0.2.14 
│ │ ├─┬ contextify@0.1.2 
│ │ │ └── bindings@0.3.0 
│ │ ├── cssom@0.2.3 
│ │ └── request@2.9.202 
│ └── xmlhttprequest@1.3.0 
└── navigator@1.0.1 

aeka ~/test$
```

Comment: You have more packages than I do, I wonder if that's the issue...  I tried installing contextify and got this:

npm ERR! contextify@0.1.2 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! `cmd "/c" "node-gyp rebuild"` failed with 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the contextify@0.1.2 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the contextify package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild

Comment: Could you post the commands you used to install your packages?

Comment: You shouldn't install those directly; `contextify` was installed automatically as a dependency of installing `jquery` (hence it being shown under). If you install it directly, it won't be under `jquery`'s own `node_modules`, so it wouldn't help anyway. It reads like something's wrong with `contextify`'s build process on your machine. Do you perhaps need to `apt-get install build-essential`?

Comment: Woah, "39 upgraded, 29 newly installed, 4 to remove and 337 not upgraded".  So it's no wonder something in there was needed!  It also broke my ASCII graphics in the extended range (âââ¬ jquery@1.7.2), but that's a minor concern at the moment.  Any idea how to fix a similar issue for Windows?

Comment: Haha, whew! Unfortunately I'm not much of a Windows buff, but I wonder if it's the same underlying cause? (lack of compiler) I'm not sure how you'd convince npm to even use a specific compiler on Win, though… :|

Comment: Well for the time being, you've gotten me up and running, so I can work on the meat of my project.  If I can get it running on Windows later, much the better.  Thanks!

Comment: No probs! For what it's worth, the spider @J-P linked is by [mikael](https://github.com/mikeal), of [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) fame, so I'd hazard it's worth a look too, if only for learning about how he chose to design it.

Comment: I looked at it briefly, but it looks like a more generic large scale production than what I need for now (Mine is currently just scraping a known site for links to .txt files).  I did, however, end up needing request(), so I recognized the connection!  Thanks to your help, I was able to get the script up and running yesterday on my server!